# Camel onCompletion not working on exception after a split() - bug?

Tags: apache-camel

I created a minimal example /unit test:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class OnCompletionTest extends CamelTestSupport{

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:in")
    private Endpoint in;
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:completion")
    private MockEndpoint mockComp;
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:out")
    private MockEndpoint mockOut;

    @Test
    public void good() throws InterruptedException {
        mockComp.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        mockOut.setExpectedMessageCount(2);
        //
        context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(in, Arrays.asList("1","2"));
        //
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void exception() throws InterruptedException {
        mockComp.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        mockOut.setExpectedMessageCount(2);

        //
        mockOut.whenAnyExchangeReceived(exchange -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("");});
        try {
            context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(in, Arrays.asList("1","2"));
            fail();
        } catch (CamelExecutionException e){

        }
        //
        mockOut.assertIsSatisfied();
        mockComp.assertIsSatisfied();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isUseRouteBuilder() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // @formatter:off
                from(in)
                        .onCompletion().to(mockComp).end()
                        .split().body()
                            //.stopOnException()
                            //.shareUnitOfWork()
                .to(mockOut)
                ;
                // @formatter:on
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The test "exception" is failing but it shouldn't. Because onCompletion should be used in all cases (error or not). Using stopOnException and/or shareUnitOfWork doesn't help.
If i remove the split, onCompletion is used in both cases.

Is there a way to get this onCompletion block working (in my real rout i use this for kind of audit logging)?

Regardless of a possible solution should i file a bug about this?

Comment: Have you tried adding an aggregationStrategy to your split? Also, wireTap should serve you equally well for your audit-purpose. That's what we're using in our routes to perform audit-logging.

Comment: yeah - in my real route there is an aggregation strategy. The problem with wiretap is where to put it. i need it at the real end - in this case not the end of the split but where the original exchange is finished.

Comment: Okay, so I guess that didn't solve the issue then either? Regarding the wireTap I'd put it just before sending it to your final endpoint. The exchange should look just as it would within the onComplete, unless you need some headers that are appended within the to-endpoint? E.g. JMS-headers etc.

Comment: @dermoritz I executed your test with same results. Since you already have have a unit test that demonstrates the issue, why don't you post it in the camel user forums? I think this is the right think to do before opening a JIRA as described in http://camel.apache.org/support.html . And please don't forget to add feedback here if you solve it! It is an interesting case